# Respond to HTTP HEAD requests using ASP.NET (vb)

Tags: vb.net, head

I have a server making a head request to a database dump I've created. The remote server does this to make sure that it's not using excessive bandwidth when not necessary.

However, due to some other circumstances outside my control this causes the script to be hit twice: once for the head request, and then another time to download the data.

What I'd like is to have the script I've written detect the head request, send back a couple of headers (e.g. last modified is right now, filesize different than before), and exit. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still unanswered, I'll give it a try, even though I don't do much ASP.NET.

I'm only familiar with ASP.NET MVC 3, so here's some example code I got to work for responding to HEAD requests:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("NewHeader", "Value")

    Return View()
End Function

<ActionName("Index")>
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Head)>
Function IndexHead() As ActionResult
    Return Index()
End Function
```

I'm not sure if this still sends content or not, but I didn't see any content in Firefox (with Live HTTP Headers) or with a `WebRequest`. It could just be that those two ignore content; I wasn't able to confirm with with my packet sniffer, though.

Also, if you want more control over headers, you'll need IIS 7.0, as mentioned in this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx).